# GAE google task api "Error: Not Found"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-tasks-api

I have followed this google task api tutorial on GAE: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/getting_started_with_tasks_api

I have tried everything they did.

I have added this in the route:

```
                        ('/mytask', mytask),
                        ('/mytask'+ decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
```

yet I am getting following error:

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /oauth2callback?state=http://sadaf2605.appspot.com/mytask:rBFVjEpyDnAPoYsm-J6COToxMzY1NDM0ODg4&code=4/DVdE2clKgg1yfLTcFL9AdGzszVvj.snlDhp_QkQYZgrKXntQAax1q0onUewI was not found on this server.
```

Can you guys please tell me where can I expect a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You're not attaching the handler to the right URL: you're prefixing it with '/mytask'. If you don't want it to serve on the default /oauth2callback, then you need to pass `callback_path` when you create the `OAuth2Decorator`